# PHP Session based authentication issue with blocking api calls

Tags: php, session, authentication, slim

On my slim app i use cookie based authentication, on successful authentication i set $_SESSION['id'], so i can know user is authenticated, now i want before any API call to check if user is authenticated, BUT i dont want to check that if user is calling post method to authenticate. Down below is my index.php and as you can see there i'm checking session, and if cookie is not set, i just return http error. But on this way i'm blocked to do auth call, and that means i can't log to app. What is best way to disable that check on authentication post call ?

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
    http_response_code(423);
    exit('You are not authenticated, please authenticate!');
}
$app = new \Slim\App;

require_once 'rest/authentication/authentication.php';
require_once 'rest/users/users.php';
require_once 'rest/control-groups/controlGroups.php';
require_once 'rest/clients/clients.php';
require_once 'rest/attendants/attendants.php';
require_once 'rest/calendar/caringCalendar.php';

$app->run();
```

EDIT:

This is how my index.php looks, i did it thx to Rob's answer.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();
$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->add(function($request,$response,$next) {
    // public route array
    $public = array('authenticate');

    // get the first route in the url

    $uri = $request->getUri();
    $path = explode('/', $uri->getPath());
    $requestRoute = $path[1];

    // if the first route in the url is not in the public array, check for logged in user
    if (!in_array($requestRoute,$public) && empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
        http_response_code(423);
        exit('You are not authenticated, plase authenticate!');
    }

    // public route or valid user
    return $next($request, $response);
});

require_once 'rest/authentication/authentication.php';
require_once 'rest/users/users.php';
require_once 'rest/control-groups/controlGroups.php';
require_once 'rest/clients/clients.php';
require_once 'rest/attendants/attendants.php';
require_once 'rest/calendar/caringCalendar.php';

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use [Middleware](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html) for your routes and create a public list of routes that don't need authentication. 
*Note: This will only use the first route in the url structure.*

```
    $app = new Slim\App;

// add middleware to routes
$app->add(function($request,$response,$next) {
    // public route array
    $public = array('authenticate');

    // get the first route in the url
    $uri = $request->getUri();
    $path = explode('/',$uri->getPath());
    $requestRoute = $path[1];

    // if the first route in the url is not in the public array, check for logged in user
    if (!in_array($requestRoute,$public) && empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
        return $response
                ->withStatus(401)
                ->write('You are not authenticated, please authenticate!');
    }

    // public route or valid user
    return $next($request,$response);
});

$app->get('/authenticate',function($request,$response) {
    return $response->write('Login');
});

$app->get('/admin',function($request,$response) {
    return $response->write('Admin page');
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: Thank you sir that works, i updated my question with changes that i made, can you take another look and check if it's ok.

Comment: @SuperMario'sYoshi I updated my answer.  I would use Slim's response methods of withStatus() and write() for consistency purposes.  If you decide to use what you have, the proper http status would be 401.